# What is the effect of charge of Sun induced on the Earth as compared to gravity?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, electromagnetic-induction, coulombs-law

As we know gravity is a less attractive force than the for of electric and magnetic fields. My question is where does the effect of magnetic field go while gravity has pull on earth.

At this point in time, I know about "Van Allen Belt" that has been formed due to induced magnetic field. But my question is the force of magnetic fields must be greater than the effect of gravity. From this point I concluded that it might be possible that we are levitating in the magnetic field of the sun instead of pull by the gravity or there is the effect of both or more forces.

I want you to explain the effect of gravitational force and that of magnetic forces on Earth by Sun with the help of coulombs law and gravitational law.

Answer (score 0):

Your questions seems to ask whether there is an electromagnetic force between the Sun and the Earth which has an appreciable impact on our orbit.

The Earth's magnetic field is very weak locally, barely enough to align a compass point.The Sun's is about twice as strong, on average, but has intense variations associated with sunspots etc.

The affect of the interaction between the two can be assumed to be vanishingly small (compared with gravity) without performing any calculations if one takes into account that the direction of the Sun's magnetic field verses periodically (every 11 years). If we were 'levitating' on a cushion of electromagnetism we would feel the effects of the reversal.

There is a radiation pressure acting on the Earth from the impact of EM radiation emitted by the sun, but it is tiny- about 10N per square kilometre.